# Where is the syntax error in this simple print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I get an error here?

```
C:\Users\Daapii\Desktop>"foo.py"  
  File "C:\Users\Daapii\Desktop\foo.py", line 26
    print "test"
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  (Why u no tell us more? :)

Comment: fair enough, python 3 yes.

Comment: Cool, then it looks like Joe has answered your question below.  Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is Python 3, then the `print` function now requires parenthesis. Try `print("test")`.

(EDIT: If Python continues to make you want to eat your keyboard, [this might help](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chocolate%20keyboard&tbm=isch).)

Comment: And the user can figure out if it is Python3 by putting `import sys`, and `print (sys.version)` at the top of the program.

Comment: thanks @all will try it out and report back :) and thanks for the chocolate keyboard link

Comment: +1 for working chocolate into your answer.

Comment: that did the trick, I'm quite new to python so I'm still struggling, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Joe: I think you used 'brackets' when you meant 'parenthesis'.

Comment: True, 'parentheses' always means `()` but brackets is a broader term that could include `()`, `[]`, `⟨⟩` etc. Maybe it's a British English vs American English thing? Either way, no reason for me not to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a function in Python 3:

```
print ("test")
```

Find other changes here: [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)